# Hide "edit" and "delete" links

Tags: navigation

I am adding images to a mega menu and they are lining up nice, but when an anonymous user is viewing the site, the "edit" and "delete" links are visible over the image. Is there a way to hide them?

Comment: Check the permissions and make sure that anonymous users doesn't have some permission that it shouldn't have...

Comment: It looks like the permissions are set correctly. I am not seeing that user having edit/delete privileges.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the links as an anonymous user? If it let's you edit them without logging in then you have a serious problem that needs to be fixed. If it doesn't, then there might just be a problem in the cache, where the version of the menu being created for the admin is being served to anonymous users.

Comment: When I click as an anonymous user, I get an "access denied" page message.

Comment: What's weird is that when I flush cache the links appear and then disappear after some time.